# Modulus of the complex number $z=t^{ib}$ where $t>0$ and $b \in \mathbb R$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let us consider a complex number $z=t^{a+ib}$ where $t>0$ is a real number and $a,b \in \mathbb R.$
Now I want to find the modulus of $z$, that is, $|z|.$
Now I have done,
$$|z|=\left|t^{a+ib}\right|=t^{a}\left|t^{ib}\right|.$$
So, we need to find only $\left|t^{ib}\right|$. I know that, if $t=e$ then $\left|t^{ib}\right|=1$, but what about $t\ne e$ but $t>0$. Can you please help me to solve this question? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $t^{ib}$ is *defined* to be equal to $e^{ib \log t}$

Answer (score 4):

$t^{ib}=e^{ib\log(t)}$

So, $|t^{ib}|=|e^{ib\log(t)}|=1$

Answer (score 1):

Your work is not entirely correct.

$t^{a+ib}$ is potentially multivalued, depending on what $t$ is, because the logarithm is multivalued. The value(s) should be computed as follows.

Since $t>0$, $\log t$ assumes the possible values $\ln t +2\pi ik$ for integral $k$  (here, $\ln$ is the real-valued function of a positive real variable). Thus

$$t^{a+ib} = e^{(a+ib)\log t} = e^{(a+ib)(\ln t + 2\pi ik)}$$
$$= e^{a\ln t -2\pi kb + i(b\ln t  + 2\pi ka)}$$
so that
$$|t^{a+ib}| = e^{a\ln t -2\pi kb} = t^a e^{-2\pi kb}$$
For convenience, we can replace $k$ by $-k$ since it represents any integer, and we can say that the possible values of $|t^{a+ib}|$ are $\boxed{t^a e^{-2\pi kb}}$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$. The principal value, taking $k=0$, is then $\boxed{t^a}$.